# MS Outlook MailItem as MIME message

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2007, mime-message

I have been looking for some time for a way to get an Outlook MailItem as a MIME-Message, but without much luck so far.

What I found is this here: http://www.office-outlook.com/outlook-forum/index.php/m/600993/, which would mean that I would either have to use a third party library or get into Extended MAPI.

Is there no other way to get a complete MailItem as MIME in Outlook 2007 with VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is either Extended MAPI (IConverterSession) or Redemption (RDOMail/SafeMailItem.SaveAs).

You can of course explicitly built the MIME message in your code one property at a time...